# Java Web Start return value - workaround

Tags: java, java-web-start

I know that returning a value from a JWSapp to the "calling" page cannot be done.
However, I use this JWSapp to get user ID from its biometric information.
The idea is that when you try to login, a button allows to launch the JWSapp that will deal with the biometric tasks and then return the user's idea.

Still, as I said, from a JWSapp I cannot send back the id to auto-complete the field. I found this post: [Returning a value from a java web start application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987984/returning-a-value-from-a-java-web-start-application) but I really need to keep the JWS (external constraints)...

So there's my question: is there any workaround to get the id back?
**Thank you in advance :)**

Comment: what is "calling page" supposed to mean? Are you talking about HttpRequests to **external / non-local** Java webstart apps? Well, in any case : of course its **always** possible to "return" data, just have your external webapp output the value directly via HTTP - you might want to consider using SOAP or JSON, though because its much more efficient and was actually created for these kinds of purposes. After parsing the result of your HttpRequest you will find your value where its supposed to be ... SOAP basically is a wrapped, shiny & convenient HttpRequest with massively enhanced functionality

Comment: I mean that I run the JavaWebStart app from a button in a web page (a JSF page to be specific). Thank you for your answer. I see the idea of sending a value via SOAP/HTTP but how does it can "update" a field in my web page ? In fact, the value would be sent to the server, which through a web service could get the value, but once here, how does it can update a field on the client's page?

Comment: i haven written any answer yet ... and i think you should consider a progamming basics - tutorial, also : computer technology / IT in general. You wont be able to achieve anything with your current skill-level. Maybe try targetting a much smaller goal for now, start with a hello-world application on your local computer, use programming tutorials and read (a lot) about computers.